# Why is Matrix.MutiplyMV rotating vectors clockwise?

Tags: android, math, vector, matrix

I am baffled as to why android's matrix class's multiplyMV method seems to be rotating my vector coordinate clockwise, when I thought it would be counter-clockwise.

In this code pos is the vector coordinate and set to be **<0.0f, 5.0f ,0.0f>**, and the matrix will rotate the coordinate vector by -45 degrees about the Z axis. I would expect the result vector coordinate in the <+,+> quadrant, namely **<3.535534, 3.535534, 0.0>**. But instead, it rotates the coordinate in the opposite direction, <-,+> quadrant, namely **<-3.535534, 3.535534, 0.0>**.

```
Matrix4 mtxRot = Matrix4.InitRotateEulerXYZ(0.0f, 0.0f, -45f);
pos.Set(0.0f, 5.0f ,0.0f);
mtxRot.TransformCoordVec(pos);
```

Here's my in Matrix4.InitRotateEulerXYZ

```
public static Matrix4 InitRotateEulerXYZ(float x, float y, float z)
{
    Matrix4 rotMatrix = new Matrix4();

    /*  XYZ = | cz*cy,   sz*cx + cz*sy*sx,  sz*sx - cz*sy*cx |
              | -sz*cy,  cz*cx - sz*sy*sx,  cz*sx + sz*sy*cx |
              | sy,     -cy*sx,             cy*cx            |  */

    // Convert from degrees to radians
    x = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(x);
    y = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(y);
    z = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(z);

    rotMatrix.GetArray()[0] =  MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Cos(y);
    rotMatrix.GetArray()[1] = -MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Cos(y);
    rotMatrix.GetArray()[2] =  MathHelper.Sin(y);

    rotMatrix.GetArray()[4] =  (MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Cos(x)) + (MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Sin(y) * MathHelper.Sin(x));
    rotMatrix.GetArray()[5] =  (MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Cos(x)) - (MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Sin(y) * MathHelper.Sin(x));
    rotMatrix.GetArray()[6] = -(MathHelper.Cos(y) * MathHelper.Sin(x));

    rotMatrix.GetArray()[8 ] = (MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Sin(x)) - (MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Sin(y) * MathHelper.Cos(x));
    rotMatrix.GetArray()[9 ] = (MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Sin(x)) + (MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Sin(y) * MathHelper.Cos(x));
    rotMatrix.GetArray()[10] =  MathHelper.Cos(y) * MathHelper.Cos(x);

    return rotMatrix;
}
```

And here is my Matrix4.TransformCoordVec method

```
public Vector3 TransformCoordVec(Vector3 vec3)
{
    Matrix4.inVec[0] = vec3.X;
    Matrix4.inVec[1] = vec3.Y;
    Matrix4.inVec[2] = vec3.Z;
    Matrix4.inVec[3] = 1.0f; // homogeneousCoord

    Matrix.multiplyMV(Matrix4.outVec, 0, this.matrix, 0, Matrix4.inVec, 0);     

    vec3.X = Matrix4.outVec[0]; vec3.Y = Matrix4.outVec[1]; vec3.Z = Matrix4.outVec[2];     
    return vec3;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**FIXED**

InitRotateEulerXYZ and my Quaternion ToMatrix() methods needed to be transposed in order to make rotation counter-clockwise for positive angles. Here are the corrected methods.

Quaternion.ToMatrix

```
/**Converts a quanternion to its equivilant matrix form**/
public Matrix4 ToMatrix()
{       
    // First, lets check if we need to re-normalize our quaternion
    if(normalRegenerationCount <= 1000)
    {
        Normalize();
    }

    float x2 = x * x;
    float y2 = y * y;
    float z2 = z * z;
    float xy = x * y;
    float xz = x * z;
    float yz = y * z;
    float wx = w * x;
    float wy = w * y;
    float wz = w * z;

    Matrix4 result = new Matrix4();

    // This calculation would be a lot more complicated for non-unit length quaternions
    // Note: The constructor of Matrix4 expects the Matrix in column-major format like expected by
    //   OpenGL
    result.Set_11(1.0f - (2.0f * (y2 + z2)));
    result.Set_12(2.0f * (xy + wz)); 
    result.Set_13(2.0f * (xz - wy));        
    result.Set_14(0.0f);        

    result.Set_21(2.0f * (xy - wz));  
    result.Set_22(1.0f - (2.0f * (x2 + z2)));
    result.Set_23(2.0f * (yz + wx));
    result.Set_24(0.0f); 

    result.Set_31(2.0f * (xz + wy)); 
    result.Set_32(2.0f * (yz - wx)); 
    result.Set_33(1.0f - (2.0f * (x2 + y2))); 
    result.Set_34(0.0f);

    result.Set_41(0.0f);
    result.Set_42(0.0f);        
    result.Set_43(0.0f);        
    result.Set_44(1.0f);

    return result;
}
```

Matrix.InitRotateEulerXYZ

```
public static Matrix4 InitRotateEulerXYZ(float x, float y, float z)
{
    Matrix4 rotMatrix = new Matrix4();

    // Convert from degrees to radians
    x = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(x);
    y = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(y);
    z = MathHelper.DegreesToRadians(z);

    rotMatrix.matrix[0] =  MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Cos(y);
    rotMatrix.matrix[1] = (MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Cos(x)) + (MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Sin(y) * MathHelper.Sin(x)); 
    rotMatrix.matrix[2] = (MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Sin(x)) - (MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Sin(y) * MathHelper.Cos(x));

    rotMatrix.matrix[4] =  -MathHelper.Cos(y) * MathHelper.Sin(z);
    rotMatrix.matrix[5] =  (MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Cos(x)) - (MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Sin(y) * MathHelper.Sin(x));
    rotMatrix.matrix[6] =  (MathHelper.Cos(z) * MathHelper.Sin(x)) + (MathHelper.Sin(z) * MathHelper.Sin(y) * MathHelper.Cos(x)); 

    rotMatrix.matrix[8 ] =  MathHelper.Sin(y); 
    rotMatrix.matrix[9 ] = -(MathHelper.Cos(y) * MathHelper.Sin(x));
    rotMatrix.matrix[10] =  MathHelper.Cos(y) * MathHelper.Cos(x);

    return rotMatrix;
}
```

Comment: Try aggregating a sequence of calls to one of the rotateM methods to generate the final rotation matrix and note the differences (if any) when compared to your approach.  Post the new code here either way.

Comment: Try multiplying by the transpose of this matrix and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying the matrices you have created, by setting X and Y to 0 as arguments in `InitRotateEulerXYZ`, and multiplying by (0, 5, 0, 0) you get:

```
| cos(θ) sin(θ)    0     0 | | 0 |   | 5*sin(θ) |
|-sin(θ) cos(θ)    0     0 | | 5 |   | 5*cos(θ) |
|    0     0       1     0 | | 0 | = |     0    |
|    0     0       0     0 | | 0 |   |     0    |
```

Substituting θ=-π/4, the resulting vector is given by:

```
| 5*sin(-π/4) |   | -5*sin(π/4) |
| 5*cos(-π/4) |   |  5*cos(π/4) |
|      0      | = |       0     |
|      0      |   |       0     |
```

Which is exactly the answer you have been seeing.  So, I suggest it's not a problem with the Android matrix multiplication routines.  You should recheck the derivation of your matrix multiplications or simply choose one of those [already derived at another site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_rotations#Euler_rotations) and adapt your code accordingly.

Alternatively, you can use the built in [setRotateEulerM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#setRotateEulerM%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) method and have the system generate it for you.  You just need to make certain the order of the matrix multiplications is consistent with your intent, as there are a variety of ways to generate these matrices.

One other thing to consider is that using Euler Rotation matrices are generally a poor method for generalized rotations as they are subject to things like gimble lock.  You may want to consider one of the [Axis/Angle methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis-angle_representation) such as [Rodrigues' method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), or by using [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation).  The Android library appears to have [native implementations of axis/angle routines](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#rotateM%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) if you would prefer to use one of those instead.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day! My derivations were incorrect. They were geared for a left handed coordinate system I suppose. I am glad that the android methods have no problems. Indeed, I use quaternions and angle axis too. In fact, I came across this issue when I had noticed that I had been getting opposite angles for my quaternion-vector rotation vs my quaternion generated rotation matrix rotation.